# LCD controller board showing image four times

Tags: display, external-display, lcd, controller

I had a broken laptop and I wanted to take advantage of its screen, so I disassembled it and noticed that the display is a Quanta QD15TL07:

[image]

So I found this controller board on eBay: http://r.ebay.com/94mdmr
Model M.NT68676.2A

[image]

The problem comes when I've connected it to the display, the image is shown four times on it:

[image]

I'd like to know if anybody has experienced the same problem or if you guys know if I have to change something on the board.

Comment: Wrong sync signals? Wrong resolution?

Comment: How can I check that?? I don't think the resolution is a problem since it doesn't matter if I connect something to the display or not, it always shows the same way.

Comment: If the controller board puts out, say, 640x480, and the LCD resolution is 1280x960, you'll see 4 frames as four images, like in your photo. Do you have a manual for the controller board? Diagram? Anything?

Comment: On eBay description it says Max Resolution 2048x1152: http://i1244.photobucket.com/albums/gg564/oupin/1-9878_zpsj9p9nuu7.jpg

I've also found this manual with diagrams: http://www.vslcd.com/Specification/M.NT68676.2A.pdf and also another PDF here: http://www.elecrealm.com/down/html/?39.html

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try to get into the "factory mode" as described in the second link? Are there any other menu items besides those visible in the picture? You shouldn't touch brightness, contrast, and the color temperature settings, but maybe "LVDS Map" does anything useful? Also see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/30vlvn/monitor_bad_or_controller_bad/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dirkt I've been able to enter the factory mode menu, LVDS Map was set to 1, so apparently, everything is ok there...

Comment: Did you try changing it to 0? Are there any other interesting menu items?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52475/discussion-between-jv-lobo-and-dirkt).

Answer (score 0):

the m.nt68676 board itself IS universal, but it needs the correct firmware for your panel. i know, youre thinking "oh cool i'll put the right firmware on it" im gonna stop you right there and say you cant easily reflash the firmware. it requires a special programming board and adapter that costs more than the m.nt68676 itself :(
ive had mixed luck with ebay ones:
ebay listings that already have the correct model in the listing itself are fine. these are boards already programmed for that exact model. 
listings with no model number applied will ask you to give them the model number before they ship. they flash the firmware they THINK is for yours, and send it to you. these havn't worked out well for me. (sorry to reply to an old post but im leaving a breadcrumb for anyone else following this google trail to their issue)